# Difference between Sip client and IMS client

Tags: android, sip, ims

What is the difference between SIP client Vs IMS Client? Can we call sip client as IMS client?.

Ex: Linphone, Sipdroid, Imsdroid are some sip clients available for Android. Are there any specific IMS Clients for android?

Comment: IMSDroid is the first fully featured open source SIP/IMS client for android.

Answer (score 4):

If you think of SIP as the protocol engine for voice/video communications over IP, then IMS is the rest of the car.  Done right, IMS takes SIP to a whole new level of capability, just like a Cadillac takes an engine and makes you want to sit behind it barrelling down the highway at 70 miles and hour.

Conversely, IMS done wrong is like sitting in a Geo Metro in the rain when the windows don't roll up.

So what does IMS give you that SIP doesn't?  Here are some key points.

- IMS provides a logical conceptual architecture between the different parts of a communications network.  For example, you have a logical entity known as a P-CSCF whose job it is to proxy connections from clients into the core of the network.  This P-CSCF speaks SIP, but not only that, it can do a whole bunch of other useful things, like protect the core against SIP denial of service attacks.
- IMS provides a framework for charging.  The IMS world view comes from the telcos and as you might expect they take the ability to charge for services very seriously.  IMS uses Diameter as its foundational protocol for this function.

  - IMS provides a way of hooking in new services simply by adding application servers that implement that function, and not rearchitecting the entire network.  For example, if you wanted to add voicemail, you plug in a voicemail app server and configure your IMS core to send traffic to it when a call is unanswered.

As you can see, for a client to know IMS it needs to know more than just SIP. From the client's point of view, many of the IMS functions need certain SIP headers to be present to function, and your standard SIP client isn;t going to have them.  A good example would be P-Access-Network-Info.

Answer (score 2):

SIP is a basic singnalling protocol of IMS. You can use sip client as IMS client. I have an experience on using Sipdroid a long time ago and it worked fine.
Asterisk is one of the sip client as well.

Comment: Could you provide some additional links as sources for your explanation and for further research?

Comment: You may get the source here. : https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout

Comment: and also you can get the Asterisk app from google play but i'm not sure they're open the source.

Answer (score 0):

IMS is IP Multimedia Subsystem. It uses SIP protocol as per 3GPP specification .Mainly used for Voice transfer.
SIP protocol is defined by IETF.

IMS-Droid is ims client for android

Answer (score 0):

IMS is an architectural framework  for multimedia services standardized by 3GPP. IMS uses SIP protocol for signalling. In addition to 
standard SIP headers ( as defined in IETF SIP RFCS ) 3GPP defines specific sip headers ( Eg. The headers starting in P- like P-Asserted-Identity)  and signalling flows. 
Hence when considering conformance to 3GPP specs, **a SIP client need not be an IMS client.** 
IMSDroid is an IMS Client for Android.